# Doctrine2 inheritance - 1452 : Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm, mysql-error-1452

I deployed my projet on a new server and the error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" shows up when i try to INSERT a class with inheritance :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="prosante")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class ProSante extends Base
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $firstName;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="base")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\MyBundle\Entity\BaseRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"base" = "Base",
 *                        "prosante" = "ProSante",
 *                        "pharmacie" = "Pharmacie"})
 */

abstract class Base
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Log :

```
[2012-06-11 15:42:46] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO base (name) VALUES (?) ({"1":"Blabla"}) [] []
[2012-06-11 15:42:46] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO prosante (id, firstname) VALUES (?, ?) ({"1":"0","2":"PATRICK"}) [] []
```

I don't know what to do since the error doesn't show up when i do the same INSERT on localhost.

**EDIT**
I check "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();" after manualy insert a new "Base" into my database, its doesn't return 0, i don't understand.

**SOLUTION** It was a driver problem, i change it and it works.

Comment: Could you explain the problem? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears doctrine is interpreting "Base" as its own table. I think what you want to achieve here is to have your Base class as a mapped super class.

To do this simply annotate it as:

@MappedSuperclass

And then you can safely extend it into your other Entities..

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses

Comment: I want doctrine to interpert Base as its own table cause i use "Class Table Inheritance" : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance but it failed at the INSERT

Comment: Ah I see, have a look at the "show create table" for those Entities and see if you can work out the foreign key constraints being placed, and why they'd be there. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Okay okay, thanks anyway but the foreign key constraints seem okay but the log are strange it's like doctrine doesn't know the last id insert.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced quite a similar problem and spent a lot of time searching for its cause, so I allow myself to share my solution here as this is the closest question I found on SO. Hope this may help some people :)

### In my case

Doctrine was throwing the same foreign key constraint violation exception, although the auto-generated key in the first query (for base class) was successfully passed on to the second query (for subclass). Second query was still failing with this constraint violation and transaction was rolled back.

Digging into logs (I'm using MariaDB on CentOS), I found this error:

`[ERROR] Transaction not registered for MariaDB 2PC, but transaction is active`

### My solution

It turned out my MariaDB service was improperly installed or updated (I don't know exactly, someone else did it).

Running [`mysql_upgrade`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/) solved my issue.